# DefaultValue for Pen color and Width

Tags: c#, winforms, border, rectangles, graphic

I want to draw a rectangle shape and text.I have a border thickness and a border Brush property in my user control.But I getting a rectangle without border.

**My code:**

```
float borderThickness;
[Description(""), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(1.0)]
public float BorderThickness 
{
  get {
        return borderThickness;
  }
  set {
        borderThickness = value; 
        Invalidate();
      }
}

//it is hex value.
Color borderBrush;
[Description(""), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue("FF0000")]
public Color BorderBrush {
   get {
         return borderBrush;
   }
   set {
         borderBrush = value; 
         Invalidate();
   }
}
```

**Draw and Paint:**

```
void DrawRect(Color br, float x, float y, float w, float h)
{
    g.DrawRectangle(br, x, y, w, h);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Pen selPen = new Pen(this.BorderBrush,this.BorderThickness);
    this.Text = Number;
    DrawRect(selPen,this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Comment: From the first glance you are mixing field initializer and `DefaultValueAttribute`. Latter will not set `1.0` value to your property, it's only used by `PropertyGrid` to set bold text when property value is not equal to it. Unless you are setting them somewhere your properties have default value (e.g. `BorderThickness = 0`). Try setting initial values explicitly, e.g. `float borderThickness = 1f;`.

Comment: _DrawRect(selPen,this.ClientRectangle);_ DrawRectangle will overdraw the last pixel right and bottom () since it draw from the pixel center), so you need to make the rectangle smaller by 1 pixel..

Comment: thank you! I have removed DefaultValue and added float borderThickness = 1f; Color borderBrush = Color.Red. Its working now.@Sinatr